# Find biases and scaling factors from multiple measurements to calibrate measurement data

Tags: math, noise, measurement

Let's define that we have a process over time, like acceleration, position etc. f(t). This is the ground truth that is happening.

Then we apply a measurement process in form m(t) = k*f(t)+b, where k is a scaling factor, and b is bias and noise combined. I assume that the noise is uniform, and with large enough data set will average out, so I don't care much about that.

For example I'm measuring rotation with n accelerometers at different lengths from the center of rotation. Then k would be the length from the center of rotation (plus minus all sorts of errors), and b would be bias terms, like gravity etc. Bur for now let's concentrate on the 1D case for simplicity.

If we have n measurements, each would have their own scaling factors and biases, is there a way of getting them (relative or absolute) extracted from the data?

Thus far I've gotten relative scaling factors out while testing, by numerically differentiating the data, and then comparing the differentiated functions to first one, and then averaging the result. I assume this works because differentiation gets rid of constants, but how would I approach getting out the bias terms?

I haven't gotten any good enough solutions, but I've tried to compute the following for the biases:
For n=2 measurements:

```
m1(t) = k1 * f(t) + b1
m2(t) = k2 * f(t) + b2

m2(t) - m1(t) = f(t) * (k2 - k1) + b2 - b1
```

If we make the assumption that b1 = 0, then we get relative (I think) bias between the two functions, and solving for b2 yields:

```
b2 = m2(t) - m1(t) - f(t) * (k2 - k1)
```

And if we are going with relative bias, we can assume that m1(t) == f(t) and getting us:

```
b2 = m2(t) - m1(t)*(k2 - k1 + 1)
```

This is assuming I didn't do any mistakes in calculation. If this is the case I have problem in implementation, but that is more trivial to solve than wrong thinking process.

Comment: Just to be clear you have m1 and m2 at various times, but not f?

Comment: @dmuir Yes. The underlying process remains the same, but the measurements are from different locations (like multiple accelerometers around a spinning disk, measuring at the same time. The forces are multiple of distance from center, but the angular acceleration is the same)